# Sci Fi/Adventure Anime of the late 70s or 80s

Tags: story-identification, anime

I am looking for an old anime movie from 30-40 years ago, which was released on VHS in Germany.

It was definitely Japanese style anime, definitely hand drawn. I think it was a sci-fi setting, because they were using strange weapons (exploding marbles). I am not exactly sure if it was dubbed in German, English or even if it was in Japanese. I am about sure it was not a series but instead a whole movie.

I barely know anything about it anymore, the only thing I remember clearly that there were three young boys, trying to escape from something on bikes/scooters? I think three young boys and one of them drops exploding marbles.

I can't get that out of my head, maybe someone has an idea what I watched at that time.
Sorry for having not much information, I was like 6-7 and this is like 35 years back now.

Maybe the main protagonist was actually a girl, but I am not sure.

Edit: I am kinda sure that the anime style of the people was more like *Captain Future* and *Queen Millenia*. For years I actually thought it was *Queen Millenia* until I watched it and never found any of those scenes I remember. One of the kids were kinda chubby I think and I think they didn't start with weapons and somehow get them later.

Answer (score 5):

It might be [Akira (1988)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akira_(1988_film))

Japanese anime, right period, hand drawn.

Here's a scene where three young men ride motorbikes. Another gang drop exploding "marbles", or smallish round bombs. (see at 2m40s).

Comment: No it was not Akira. The protagonists were clearly kids, not teenagers. And he really throws marbles and not a molotov coctail. Still a cool scene. Iam pretty sre he used that exploding marble thing more than once. It came out nearly the same time as Nausicaä in Germany, because i remember watching that,too.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that this could be: Galaxy Express 999.

After looking up *Queen Millenia*, I saw what it looked like and Googled 1970s anime list, which brought me to: [this website](https://www.flickchart.com/movie/AD350B60A2).  The blond person looks like Queen Millenia, it's scifi, there's some kids, and at least one matched your earlier description.

Comment: The style would match, ill look into it, and will give feedback if this was the anime iam searching for.